# Set the background colour in preview

Tags: color, preview

I'm using the `preview` package to generate pages of formulas. What I want is to specify the background colour in all of the pages. It seems like the `pagecolor` package doesn't interact nicely with `preview`, and using `colorbox`, doesn't fill the entire page.

Here's my current code for rendering:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}

\PreviewEnvironment{equation*}

\PreviewBorder=1pt

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation*}
        \text{ Thing 1 }
    \end{equation*}

    \begin{equation*}
        \text{ Thing 2 }
    \end{equation*}

    \begin{equation*}
        \text{ Blah }
    \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Here, I would want the `Thing 1` to have a blue background, `Thing 2` to have a red background, and `Blah` to have a yellow background.